# MediaMuxer.stop() throws IllegalStateException under a certain condition

Tags: android-mediacodec

```
MediaCodec encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
int iColorFormat = selectColorFormat(encoder.getCodecInfo(), "video/avc");
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 800);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 16000000);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, iColorFormat);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 15);
encoder.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
encoder.start();

MediaMuxer muxer = new MediaMuxer(uriFile.getPath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
muxer.addTrack(encoder.getOutputFormat());
muxer.start();
try {
    muxer.stop();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    
}
```

The above code was created for the testing purpose. `muxer.stop()` consistently throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to stop the muxer
Stacktrace:
android.media.MediaMuxer.nativeStop(Native Method)
android.media.MediaMuxer.stop(MediaMuxer.java:454)
```

However, `muxer.stop()` works fine after `muxer.writeSampleData()` is run a few times. It seems that start() alone is not adequate to make MediaMuxer enter the right state for stopping. Could anyone shed some light on the cause?

Comment: Does it occur on more than one device ?

Comment: That is a good question. This exception happens consistently on an Android 9 device (MT3010A). I have just tested it on a Pixel 2 API 31 emulator and it did not throw the exception.